# Templating boost::bind to automatically handle multiple arguments for member function

Tags: c++, events, bind, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a class with an "Attach" function that accepts a function object and stores it into a collection.  The class itself is templated on the function signature.  Something like this:

```
template<class Signature>
class Event
{
public:

 void Attach(boost::function<Signature> signature)
 {
  MySignatures.push_back(signature);
 }

private:

 std::list<boost::function<Signature>> MySignatures;
};
```

To demonstrate usage, consider the following class:

```
class Listening
{
public:

 int SomeFunction(int x, int y, int z); 
};
```

To pass the function on `Listening` into `Event`, I would need to write:

```
 Event<int(int, int, int)> myEvent;
 Listening myListening;

 myEvent.Attach(boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(&Listening::SomeFunction), &myListening, _1, _2, _3));
```

So instead of doing so for each case which may be prone to error, I write a set of macros, as follows:

```
 #define EventArgument0(x, y)  boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(x), y)
 #define EventArgument1(x, y)  boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(x), y, _1)
 #define EventArgument2(x, y)  boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(x), y, _1, _2)
 #define EventArgument3(x, y)  boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(x), y, _1, _2, _3)
 #define EventArgument4(x, y)  boost::bind(boost::mem_fn(x), y, _1, _2, _3, _4)

 etc.
```

and then I can write:

```
 myEvent.Attach(EventArgument3(&Listening::SomeFunction, &myListening));
```

which is much easier to read (I think).   Now to my question:  how can I instead write:

```
 myEvent.Attach(EventArgument(&Listening::SomeFunction, &MyListening));
```

or even better:

```
 myEvent.Attach(&Listening::SomeFunction, &myListening);
```

, such that the event Attach will magically bind correctly with the appropriate number of arguments as contained in <Signature> (in this example, `int(int, int, int)`)?  I'm open to any template meta-programming magic you have in mind here.

Thanks.

Edit: it turns out I don't need `boost::mem_fn` here, because `boost::bind` is equivalent, so in my macro I can use:

```
bind(&MyClass::Hello, myClass, _1, _2, _3);
```

,instead of:

```
bind(mem_fn(&MyClass::Hello), myClass, _1, _2, _3);
```

The question remains however:  how to pass `&MyClass::Hello` to the event class and use template overloading to handle the `_1`, `_2`, `_3`, etc. implied by the function prototype used to template the `Event` class?

Comment: Did you try to Google/Bing for "perfect forwarding"? Assuming you can use C++0x.

Comment: I'm looking at it now, for instance here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm.  It's not clear to me how that helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overload `Attach` for different numbers of parameters in the member function:

```
template<typename R,typename T,typename U>
void Attach(R (T::*pmf)(),U* p))
{
    Attach(boost::bind(pmf,p));
}

template<typename R,typename T,typename U,typename A1>
void Attach(R (T::*pmf)(A1),U* p))
{
    Attach(boost::bind(pmf,p,_1));
}

template<typename R,typename T,typename U,typename A1,typename A2>
void Attach(R (T::*pmf)(A1,A2),U* p))
{
    Attach(boost::bind(pmf,p,_1,_2));
}
```

If you need to handle `const` member functions too then you'll need a second set of overloads.

Comment: Brilliant.  I changed it slightly to work with shared_ptr (so I can hold weak_ptr references and drop .expired() pointers before firing off the event).  Otherwise, it's a great solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Making `Attach()` a template would allow you to do what you're aiming for. The code gets messy but it let's you call it the way you want.

```
template<typename A1>
void Attach(A1 a1);

template<typename A1, typename A2>
void Attach(A1 a1, A2 a2);

template<typename A1, typename A2, typename A3>
void Attach(A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3);

template<typename A1, typename A3, typename A4>
void Attach(A1 a1, A2 a2, A3 a3, A4 a4);
```